# PrintStream Only Printing out the Last Line of Input File

Tags: java, printing

I have this code

```
public class program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String filePath = (args[0]);
            String strLine;

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));

            //Read File Line By Line and Print the content on the console
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            //System.out.println (strLine);
            PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream( //printing output to user specified text file (command line argument: outputfile)
                    args[1]+".txt"));   
                out.print(strLine);
            }
            //close the streams
            br.close();
            }
            catch(IOException e){
            System.err.println("An IOException was caught :"+e.getMessage());
            }

    }
}
```

If I invoke this program from the command line using java program input.txt output

and if input file contents were this:
hello
hi
bye

the output file would print this:
bye

It is only printing the last line of the output.

if instead of:

```
  PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream( //printing output to user specified text file (command line argument: outputfile)
                args[1]+".txt"));   
            out.print(strLine);
```

I only had

```
System.out.println (strLine);
```

within the while loop, then it would correctly print each line from the input file to the console.

Why when I try to print it to another file it only prints the last line?

Answer (score 2):

Don't create a new `PrintStream` in each loop.  Instead create the `PrintStream` prior to the while loop:

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream( ... );
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
  out.print(strLine);
}
```

Comment: by the way if you want to preserve the newlines you should use `out.println()`

Answer (score 0):

Because you are overwriting to the same file within the loop. Create the PrintStream outside of the loop not inside the loop and it should write all lines!